# Magento 2 restrict cache clean on product save action

Tags: magento-2.1

I have written a Inventory update module which will save product inventory by reading CSV file provided.

Every thing is working fine but this impacting the site performance. If I am updating 100+ products then for every single product magento is clearing cache, in **beforeSave()** method.
In class **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product** we have **beforeSave()** method, which is calling

```
$this->cleanCache();
```

in the first line.
Please suggest me.

How can I restrict this cache or remove this from **beforeSave()** method?
And from where this **beforeSave()** method is called on product save?

Comment: Are you updating the stock using Custom script?

Comment: No, I am only sending my file data to `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockItemRepositoryInterface` **save()** method as below code
`$this->_stockItemRepository->save($stockItemDo);`